# sql query: how to pick only 1 row with highest value of column2 after doing ORDER by on column1

Tags: sql

I've a table like:

```
col1,  col2,  col3
8      6       xyz
8      4       abc
9      2       def
4      3       ghi
9      5       jkl
```

I'd like to write a query which picks highest value of col2 for each unique col1 value, i.e.

```
col1,  col2,  col3
4      3      ghi
8      6      xyz
9      5      jkl
```

I know how to sort the table based on col1 see [1], but I don't know if there is an easy way to pick max col2 value without doing a JOIN. This needs to be run on a table with about 1Million rows.

[1] `select col1,col2,col3 from table ORDER BY col1`

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way in almost any database (assuming the right indexes) is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col2 = (select max(t2.col2) from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1);
```

The more traditional answer is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will return only one row, even if the maximum is duplicated.  If you want all rows when there are duplicates (as in the first query), then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is also other way is to use of both with order by which is *top(1) with ties* which is available for SQL Server

```
select top(1) with ties col1 , col2, col3 
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc)
```